# Web root option in Varnish Cache similar to `root` in nginx

Tags: nginx, caching, static, varnish, nginx-reverse-proxy

In nginx we have `root` option to serve files from a specific directory, eg: `root /var/www/data/` in nginx conf, if my url is https://mydom.com/$file_name, nginx will look for files present in `/var/www/data/$file_name` and return the file if present otherwise return 404.

Now, I want something similar option in Varnish. Is there a way where I can serve files from a specific directory? How can I tell varnish to look for files in a specific directory and return that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish is a cache, not a webserver. Varnish doesn't serve pages from a document root on the disk, but it caches responses that came from a pre-defined backend server.

Although Varnish and Nginx have some similarities, and cover some of the same use cases, they are entirely different products.

However, if you use Nginx as a reverse proxy, instead of a webserver, it won't use the `root` option either.

There is one way you can make Varnish act like a webserver, and that is by leveraging [the file module in Varnish Enterprise](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/file/). This allows Varnish to serve files from disk, but this is not available in the open source version of Varnish, only in the commercial version.